# bootstrap table not responsive even with .table-responsive .table

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

this is the code of my bootstrap table everything is okay but when i switch to mobile it is not adding that horizontal scroll i have already added table-responsive class outside  element with class .table but still it ain't working for mobile devices

```
<div class="table-responsive table-area">
      <table class="table table-striped table-dark bordered-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">✔️</th>
              <th scope="col">Questions</th>
              <th scope="col">❤️</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>

        <% allLists.forEach(item=>{ %>

              <tr>
                <th scope="row"> <input class="form-check-input checkbox-solved" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault"> </th>
                <td> <a href="<%= item.url %>"><%= item.name %></a> </td>
                <td> <input class="form-check-input checkbox-favourite" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault"> </td>
              </tr>

        <% }) %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

[image: desktop view of the table]

[image: this is the mobile view of the table]

in the mobile view it is no even displaying that green tick table coulmn

this is table css code

```
.table-area {
  margin-top: 50px;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.table-area table {
  text-align: center;
}

table a{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: #fff;
}

table a:hover {
  color: goldenrod;
}
```

i thought max-width was causing issues but i tried removing it too but it is still not working.

Can someone please help me with this code?

Comment: Try to `add overflow-x: scroll;` to parent element of the table.

Comment: it added the scroll but as i switch to mobile the scroll disappears and it is left as it was before

Comment: Your fourth question is without any space, it won't wrap.

Comment: It's hard to tell without rest of code. Try to use Developer tools in browser [F12], switch to mobile icon or resize window and find the parent element which is smaller than the table, then change their css to `overflow-x: scroll;`

Comment: okay bro i just figured it out there is an outer div holding all this which i have set to flex to align these items horizontally and vertically centered as soon as i remove the scroll works fine but it destructures the page (left aligned contents)

Comment: @Bharat thank you that fixed the issue btw i know its impractical to have that long of a word but is it still possible to break the word to avoid such silly mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from image your fourth question text is without any space and hence it's not wrapping. Typically when you expect such a long strings without the whitespace, we need to set the width so that it will force to wrap. In your case you might have to **Responsive Web Design - Media Queries**

Here is sample for wrap with fixed width. However you can combine media queries to achieve desired result on various devices

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <style>
      span {
        width: 135px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        display: inline-block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span>
      LoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsum
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds ridiculous, but editing the class from table-responsive{overflow-x:auto;...} to table-responsive{overflow-x: auto; ...} (adding a whitespace between the colon and auto in the css file you download from Bootstrap) makes the class work again.
I had the identical issue and doing this trick it worked out again.